# Hockey game score probability question

Tags: probability, random-walk

If the score of a hockey game ended at $6$-$4$.  Each team with the same equal probability of scoring the next goal.  What is the probability that the winning team was never behind for more than one goal?

How would one do this problem?

Comment: Step 1: Decide on what "probability" means in this context.

Comment: Well I figured out the total option is ${10}\choose{6}$.  So that's the denominator.  I can't figure out the numerator.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

If you want the total no. of options to be ${10 \choose 6}$, then you are adopting a probability model where e.g. each team scores the next goal with equal probability, and you condition on the final result being $6-4$.  This is a perfectly natural model but it is still a conscious choice not explicitly specified in your question.

In this model, each goal sequence is a 10-character string with 6 Ws and 4 Ls, e.g. WWLWLWWWLL.  These are the ${10\choose 6}$ strings in your denominator.  You can then simply count the strings which fail your criterion.  Any string failing your criterion must reach $0-2$ or $1-3$ or $2-4$ at some point.  So they are: any strings starting with LL, or LWLL, or WLLL, or WWLLLL, or WLWLLL, or WLLWLL, or LWWLLL, or LWLWLL.  I think those are all.

Comment: Yeah sorry for forgetting to mention the fact that each team has equal probability to score a goal!  Will fix that asap!

Comment: @Itsnhantransitive do you need more help with this?  or is the hint enough?

Comment: I think this hint is enough. I got $4/7$ as an answer!